# How to create an archive and chmod it

Tags: linux

I should create a file inside this file an archive. When I create it, I
should use `chmod` so that the archive should have 757 rights.

I did this but I failed, is this right or wrong? :

```
$ mkdir file1
$ cd file1
# here i should create an archive but how i dont know
$ chmod 757 archivename
```

Comment: As far as I remember the command is "chmod".

Comment: yes you are right.sorry my mistake i will edit

Comment: You can `touch archivename`. This will create an empty file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use touch command first:

```
bash-4.3$ mkdir a                                                                                                                                                                                                            
bash-4.3$ cd a                                                                                                                                                                                                               
bash-4.3$ pwd                                                                                                                                                                                                                
/home/cg/root/a                                                                                                                                                                                                              
bash-4.3$ touch a.txt                                                                                                                                                                                                        
bash-4.3$ chmod 757 a.txt                                                                                                                                                                                                    
bash-4.3$ ls -lrt                                                                                                                                                                                                            
total 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
-rwxr-xrwx 1 18207 18207 0 May  4 11:29 a.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need:

```
$ mkdir file1
$ cd file1
$ touch actual_file.txt
$ cd ..
$ tar czvf file1-archive.tar.gz file1/
$ chmod 757 file1-archive.tar.gz
```

This creates an archive of everything inside the file1 folder.